# Add Entity Managers and Connections width EntityManager::create

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to create multiple Entity Managers and connection width This method EntityManager::create but how can get this new entity manager after creation and use doctrine to apply different command like this : 
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=newconnection and 
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager('newconnection');

```
$isDevMode = false;
    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
    $conn = [
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'dbname' => $dbname
    ];
   // obtaining the entity manager
    return EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is this a Symfony framework application or a standalone Doctrine based application?

Comment: This is a symfony framework application, I need many connection to database and foreach database I need to create an Entity Manager and for information the access of database is stored in table so I need to retreive them and after that create new connection in Sf

Comment: It is easy enough to [configure multiple entity managers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).  Creating one on a request based approach can be a bit more challenging as the entity managers rely heavily on cached data and rebuilding the cache on each request is problematical at best.

Comment: No this is manual but I want it to be automatic because the names and pasword of databases are stored in  table

Comment: Maybe take a look at the php based configuration capability.  You could probably read from a database.  An easier approach might be to write a simple script which would read the database and then store the credentials as env variables.  Worse case might be to write a compiler pass similar to what the doctrine bundle does.